# In Hibernate 4, inner join is used for child objects while accessing objects of "one table per subclass"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join

In Hibernate 4, inner join is used for child objects while accessing objects of "one table per subclass".

[Edit: This is a bug in Hibernate 4.3.5, and it is going to be fixed in 4.3.6. https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8980 ]

I have the following classes.

Professor - Base Class

ContractProfessor - Derived Class from Professor

FulltimeProfessor - Derived Class from Professor

FulltimeProfessor contains a mandatory object of Department. [Not null at SQL]

Classroom contains an object of Professor, which can be null.

When I query Classroom, I am getting errors. When I saw the query, it is doing inner join with Department. If the classroom that it is retrieving is of ContractProfessor, then it won't have Department, and the inner join fails, and it is throwing exception.

Since, the Professor object can be null, it should always use left join for all the joins. But, it is doing inner join between FulltimeProfessor and Department. Because of that, I am getting exceptions when I try to retrieve Classroom objects.

This is working fine in Hibernate 3. But, when I use hibernate 4.3.5-Final, I am getting errors.

What should I do to fix this without changing the DB schema?

The following is the code and sql for the same.

Generated Query in Hibernate 4.3.5-Final

```
 select
     professor0_.id as id1_6_0_,
     professor0_.name as name2_6_0_,
     professor0_1_.hourlyRate as hourlyRa1_2_0_,
     professor0_2_.DepartmentId as Departme3_4_0_,
     professor0_2_.salary as salary1_4_0_,
     case
         when professor0_1_.id is not null then 1
         when professor0_2_.id is not null then 2
         when professor0_.id is not null then 0
     end as clazz_0_,
     department1_.id as id1_3_1_,
     department1_.name as name2_3_1_
 from
     Professor professor0_
 left outer join
     ContractProfessor professor0_1_
         on professor0_.id=professor0_1_.id
 left outer join
     FulltimeProfessor professor0_2_
         on professor0_.id=professor0_2_.id
 inner join
     Department department1_
         on professor0_2_.DepartmentId=department1_.id
 where
     professor0_.id=?
```

Generated Query in Hibernate 3.

```
 select
     professor0_.id as id2_1_,
     professor0_.name as name2_1_,
     professor0_1_.hourlyRate as hourlyRate3_1_,
     professor0_2_.DepartmentId as Departme3_8_1_,
     professor0_2_.salary as salary8_1_,
     case
         when professor0_1_.id is not null then 1
         when professor0_2_.id is not null then 2
         when professor0_.id is not null then 0
     end as clazz_1_,
     department1_.id as id1_0_,
     department1_.name as name1_0_
 from
     Professor professor0_
 left outer join
     ContractProfessor professor0_1_
         on professor0_.id=professor0_1_.id
 left outer join
     FulltimeProfessor professor0_2_
         on professor0_.id=professor0_2_.id
 left outer join
     Department department1_
         on professor0_2_.DepartmentId=department1_.id
 where
     professor0_.id=?
```

Professor.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Professor")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Professor {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  private String name;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Professor id: " + getId() + " name: " + getName();
  }
}
```

ContractProfessor.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ContractProfessor")
public class ContractProfessor extends Professor {
    private long hourlyRate = 1;

    public long getHourlyRate() {
        return hourlyRate;
    }

    public void setHourlyRate(long hourlyRate) {
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "ContractProfessor id: " + getId() + " name: " + getName();
    }
}
```

FulltimeProfessor.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

@Entity
@Table(name="FulltimeProfessor")
public class FulltimeProfessor extends Professor {
    private long salary = 1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DepartmentId", nullable = false)
    private Department department;

    public Department getDepartment()
    {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department)
    {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public long getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(long salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "FullTimeProfessor id: " + getId() + " name: " + getName();
    }
}
```

Department.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
public class Department
{
      private long id;

      private String name;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String toString() {
        return "Department id: " + getId() + " name: " + getName();
      }
}
```

Classroom.java

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Classroom")
public class Classroom
{
      private long id;

      private String name;

      private Professor professor;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      public long getId() {
        return id;
      }

      public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getName() {
        return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String toString() {
        return "Classroom id: " + getId() + " name: " + getName();
      }

      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
      @JoinColumn(name = "ProfessorId", nullable = true)
      public Professor getProfessor()
      {
        return professor;
      }

      public void setProfessor(Professor professor)
      {
        this.professor = professor;
      }
}
```

InnerJoinMain.java

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class InnerJoinMain
{
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
      {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProfessorService");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            int time = (int)((new Date().getTime() / 1000) % 10000);
            System.out.println(time);

            ContractProfessor cprof = new ContractProfessor();
            cprof.setName("CProf" + time);
            cprof.setHourlyRate(time);
            em.persist(cprof);

            Department dept = new Department();
            dept.setName("Dept" + time);
            em.persist(dept);

            FulltimeProfessor fprof = new FulltimeProfessor();
            fprof.setName("Fprof" + time);
            fprof.setDepartment(dept);
            fprof.setSalary(time + 10);
            em.persist(fprof);

            Classroom cls = new Classroom();
            cls.setName("Classroom" + time);
            cls.setProfessor(cprof);
            em.persist(cls);

            cls = new Classroom();
            cls.setName("Classroom" + (time+1));
            cls.setProfessor(fprof);
            em.persist(cls);

            cls = new Classroom();
            cls.setName("Classroom" + (time+2));
            em.persist(cls);

            em.getTransaction().commit();

            em.getTransaction().begin();

            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Classroom c");
            for(Classroom c : (Collection<Classroom>) query.getResultList()) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }

            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
            emf.close();
      }
}
```